# How to satisfy the constraint of Record<string, unknown> with interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

My linter is saying I shouldn't use object as a type in TS. However, a library that I'm using asks for generic types that extend object.

I'm therefore writing a generic component with the library that looks like this:

```
const Component = <T extends object>(props: CustomProps<T>): React Element => etc.
```

Since the linter is complaining, I've tried switching it to

```
const Component = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(props: CustomProps<T>): React Element => etc.
```

However, if I then do something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
  something: string;
  goes: number; 
  here: string;
}

const CallerComponent = () => Component<MyInterface> />
```

TS says that MyInterface does not satisfy the constraint Record<string, unknown>. Is there any way around this other than to do

```
interface MyInterface extends Record<string, unknown>
```

I'd rather not have to go through the entire codebase adding this to every interface so it would be great to know if there's a way I can type it where I say that T will definitely be an object.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `Record<string, unknown>` will require an index signature. Why didn't `object` work for you ? You could also try `T extends Record<keyof T, unknown>`.

Comment: Hi Titian, thanks for this - eslint has a rule against using object. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: take `eslint` rules with a grain of salt. They are there to prevent people jumping the gun, but in this case `object ` might be fine

Comment: OK thanks - just knowing that is actually very helpful. I might just ignore this line and come back to it if I have the time

Comment: You can just extend the empty object `T extends {}`

Comment: @LindaPaiste if the problem is with ESLint, the type ```{}``` also gives an error.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, Your comment is the answer. Would help the community if you would type up a quick answer with the suggestion to use `Record<keyof T, unknown>`. (And, yes to what @Raph117 said about ESLint -- it complains about any use of `object` it seems.)

Comment: ```T extends Record<keyof T, unknown>``` didn't work well because later I'll need to cast the key with ```as strings```. using type seems to be the best solution

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same issue and found that you can declare your object with `type` instead of `interface` and it solves it.

In your case it would be :

```
type MyInterface = {
  something: string
  goes: number
  here: string
}
```

Comment: This fixed the same issue for me.  I hate that this is the case, though -- I don't really get it, TBH.

Comment: You may find a bit more detail on this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42825)
and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024)